# How to get the value of <p:editor>?

Tags: java, xhtml

How can I save the value  in bean?

ajax does not work

I'm trying to valueChangeListener because it does not work

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 form-group">
 <p:outputLabel styleClass="control-label" for="..." value="#{text['name']}"/>
 <p:editor id="..." widgetVar="editorWidget" value="#{beanForm.value}" label="#{text['name']}" required="#{...}" maxlength="4000" rendered="#{...}" height="120" 
             ...  valueChangeListener="#{beanForm.setChange}" />
 <p:commandButton value="#{text['editor.clear']}" type="button" onclick="PF('editorWidget').clear();" icon="ui-icon-close" rendered="#{..}" />
                            
 <h:outputText value="#{beanForm.value}" escape="false" ... />
</div>
```